Windows 8.1 dell Inspiron bios not loading and no access to any os
I have an older Dell Inspiron windows 8.1 laptop that I do not mind taking apart, but after starting the laptop up I attempted to boot in the F12 boot options. The computer will display that the BIOS has fully loaded but it never opens, waited 12+ HOURS for the BIOS to open (overnight). I do not have access to windows 8 anymore (possibly damaged), does anyone know what's wrong or how I could fix this?

If someone labels this as off-topic, please tell me where I should post this.

It sounds like the device is bricked.  You would likely have to replace the motherboard to resolve your problem.

ok, thank you..

Would re-soldering the bios to the CPU fix the issue?

Do you have the proper equipment and skill necessary to remove, program a replacement, and install the replacement? You would need an exact replacement for that solution to work

kinda, I have soldering equipment and could make a replacement with Autodesk eagle.

Autodesk Eagle can't create ICs. You might be able to design ICs but cannot manufacture one.  I have my doubts about Autodesk Eagle being used to develop ICs.

try to remove the cmos (motherboard battery) then put it again or replace it, it can reset bios, also while your laptop is off, remove its battery then hold power bottom for 15 sec and try to run your laptop again

Thank you for your suggestion, but I have already tried that. Thanks anyway

@fatBatman Please take the tour to understand how the site works. Please understand this ISN'T a forum. In a forum suggestions such as the above would be a normal part of the threaded discussion but here please do NOT post as answers things that at best are comments with suggestions. Not even the comments section should be used for that except in specific circumstances. Even comments are primarily to ask for clarification.
